# Checkbox in a div with onclick toggle double toggles (how to block inner toggle)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox inside an `<li>` as apart of a menu. The wrapping item has a click handler which toggles the checkbox (to be consistent with the feel of the menu as whole). The problem is if the user clicks directly on the checkbox it will do its default toggle, and then the outer handler also toggles it. How can I prevent this double-toggle?

```
<li onclick='/*toggle checkbox*/'><input type='checkbox'/>...</li>
```

I've tried `disabled` but that alters the rendering, which I don't want.

I'm using jquery in case there is a feature there which helps.

Comment: _"The wrapping item has a click handler which toggles the checkbox"_ - stop trying to recreate features with JS that are already available in HTML ... and use the `label` element!

Comment: there something called as event.cancelBubble. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.cancelBubble). This might help you.

Comment: Is there any jsfiddle ?

Comment: @CBroe, I wish to have the entire "li" element toggle the checkbox. The outer element is much larger than the text which a label would have.

Comment: Just wrap everything inside your LI into a LABEL, and format it to fill the whole LI's space if necessary ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function to prevent the click from propagation up the DOM tree.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/UxPVQ/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $("#thetext").html("checbox clicked");
    });

    $("li").click(function () {
        $("#thetext").html("li clicked");
    });
});
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='checkbox' />
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="thetext">hm</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is jQuery method for this http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/